# Save a django object getting another model instance as foreign key from a form

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys

I'm stuck trying to save an instance of a model that gets from a form an instance of another model as foreign key.

Models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    custname = models.CharField() 

class Appointment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

Form

```
class AppointmentForm(forms.Form):
    basedate = forms.DateField()
    start = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.Select())
    end = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Select())
    customer = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.all())
```

The method that I'm not able to get working in a generic FormView:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        appointment = Appointment()
        appointment.user = self.request.user
        basedate = form.cleaned_data['basedate']
        start = form.cleaned_data['start']
        duration = form.cleaned_data['end']
        appointment.start = datetime.datetime.combine(basedate, start)
        appointment.end = appointment.start + datetime.timedelta(minutes=duration)
        appointment.save()
        return super(AppointmentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

What should I add in the last method to read the foreign key customer from the form, and therefore pass it to the appointment? And is there any way of filtering so that in the form only appear customers belonging to the request.user?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. A couple of things:

1) I changed the form field to a ModelChoiceField instead of multiple choice. You'll want to use a ModelChoiceField to show the relationship. I changed this from MultipleChoice since, according to your model, you only want to save one choice. You can read more on ModelChoiceFields here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/

2) In your forms, I changed the choice query to `customer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.filter(owner=request.user)`. This will filter for Customers of the specific user only.

forms.py

```
class AppointmentForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(AppointmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    basedate = forms.DateField()
    start = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.Select())
    end = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Select())
    customer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.filter(owner=request.user))
```

views.py

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AppointmentForm(request.POST, request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            appointment = Appointment()
            appointment.user = self.request.user
            basedate = form.cleaned_data['basedate']
            start = form.cleaned_data['start']
            duration = form.cleaned_data['end']
            appointment.customer = form.cleaned_data['customer']
            appointment.start = datetime.datetime.combine(basedate, start)
            appointment.end = appointment.start + datetime.timedelta(minutes=duration)       
            appointment.save()
            return super(AppointmentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
    else:
        form = AppointmentForm()
```

Comment: Now I am able to save the instance of Appointment, thanks. But two questions:In forms, use of request.user is not allowed so I can not filter customers for the current User. ¿Is there any other way to do it? And regarding ModelChoiceField, doc says should be avoided when more than 100 different choices. What would be the best approach here, so?

Comment: What is it that is preventing you from using request.user? If you're receiving an error, please post it. As for the ModelChoiceField - it's the `Select` widget that is not recommended for more than 100 different choices, not the field itself. The select widget is what you would use on your form HTML page to allow the selection. There are various ways around this - modifying the select widget, using a jQuery select widget, etc. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: Understood about the select widget. Regarding the form issue, when trying your suggestion I get: _Exception Value:  name 'request' is not defined_. I think the way to do it may be override the '_init_' method of the form class, but I can not make it work. Again, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I've edited the original post to override `init` to get request. Also, I've added `request=request` to the form initialization so the init works correctly. I'm not able to test it at the moment unfortunately, but I think that should work for you.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but I'm still getting _Exception Value: name 'request' is not defined._ in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it. The key was to override the *get* method of FormView class in views.py, rather than modifying the *init* in forms.py:

forms.py:

```
class AppointmentForm(forms.Form):
    basedate = forms.DateField()
    start = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.Select())
    end = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Select())
    customer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.all())
    ...
```

views.py:

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles GET requests and instantiates a blank version of the form.
        """
        choices_start, choices_duration = self._get_choices()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['start'].widget=forms.Select(choices=choices_start)
        form.fields['end'].widget=forms.Select(choices=choices_duration)
        form.fields['customer'].queryset=Customer.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

@Dan: Many thanks for your effort in helping me out.